# Variadic alias template to non-variadic class template

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

In trying to write a simple example for currying of metafunction classes, I wrote the following:

```
#include <type_traits>

struct first {
    template <typename T, typename U>
    using apply = T;
};

template <typename C, typename... Args>
struct curry {
    struct type {
        template <typename... OtherArgs>
        using apply = typename C::template apply<Args..., OtherArgs...>;
    };
};

int main() {
    static_assert(std::is_same<first::apply<int, char>, int>::value, ""); // OK

    using AlwaysInt = curry<first, int>::type;
    static_assert(std::is_same<AlwaysInt::apply<char>, int>::value, ""); // error
}
```

The second `static_assert` fails to compile on both gcc 5.1:

```
main.cpp:17:72: error: pack expansion argument for non-pack parameter 'U' of alias template 'template<class T, class U> using apply = T'
         using apply = typename C::template apply<Args..., OtherArgs...>;
                                                                        ^
```

and clang 3.6:

```
main.cpp:17:59: error: pack expansion used as argument for non-pack parameter of alias template
        using apply = typename C::template apply<Args..., OtherArgs...>;
                                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Same error in both cases. However, if I outsource the application in `curry` to a separate metafunction:

```
template <typename C, typename... Args>
struct eval {
    using type = typename C::template apply<Args...>;
};

template <typename C, typename... Args>
struct curry {
    struct type {
        template <typename... OtherArgs>
        using apply = typename eval<C, Args..., OtherArgs...>::type;
    };
};
```

Both compilers compile [just fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0569765cbef95983). Is there something wrong with the original example or is this just a bug in both compilers?

Comment: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1430?

Comment: @T.C. "The consensus of CWG was that this usage should be prohibited..." What? Why?

Comment: For what it's worth, VS2015 RC doesn't like it either.

Comment: @Barry Apparently it makes the alias template non-transparent. See also assorted reports on the [GCC bugzilla](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=DR%201430)

Comment: Quick fix is to make the second template parameter of first:: apply a parameter pack, but I see that this is not what your question is about. http://ideone.com/5LOp59

Comment: @T.C. Yeah Louis Dionne's use-case in [59498](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59498) is the same as what I'm doing here. The fact that the alias is non-transparent seems less important than the fact that it doesn't work...

Comment: @T.C. Like from a language perspective, it's very odd that what I am trying to do failed by [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b932e626233f3982) works fine.